# Documentation edit which is approved is entirely rewritten with the next edit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, documentation, revision-history

I'm wondering what can be done on Documentation so someone's edit, which is approved, can't be entirely removed by newer edit.

Example is: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/revisions/193?exampleId=8769 . I have made a edit with an useful information about Python's multiple inheritance and the order of inheriting superclasses. That edit was approved and after that, totally removed by edit from @JGreenwell. Now, I'm wondering: is it OK (because users approved that edit) or isn't, am I missing something?

Comment: It's "okay" if it doesn't do harm. Automatically detecting whether or not an entire rewrite happened (and if that was inappropriate) seems to be practically impossible. And restricting edits to a certain percentage or whatever metric is likely to have undesirable side effects. I can see how this is annoying, but I'd say we treat it as an edit of any other content? Was it a good edit? Did it improve what was there? If it's problematic it should be undone, and if the editor is repeatedly causing trouble (note: not saying it's the case here) then flags would be in order.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand this. Content that user entered is really good, probably better written than it was before, I just can't believe that he is removing info without any good reason. If he rewrote that info in better fashion, it would be OK, but entirely removed information is a problem as I can see. I understand that metric would be too much of implementation, but maybe we need more than 2-3 approves for a edit to become accepted.

Comment: Perhaps. Then again, given our experience with general edit review on the Q&A side of things, I'm not sure that adding more reviewers would provide a different outcome.